# ParseUser 'isAuthenticated` example

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Can anyone give me a solid, documented example of when a `currentUser` *wouldn't* be authenticated client side? Please show your sources, if applicable

**Return Value**

> Returns whether the user is authenticated.

**Discussion**

> An authenticated ParseUser is one that is obtained via a signUp or method. An authenticated object is required in order to save (with altered values) or delete it.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm wondering the same.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if i understand your question correctly but are you talking about to determine if the ParseUser.getCurrentUser() is a loged in one ?
If so, have you seen the ParseAnonymousUtils class ?

See the docs here:
https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseAnonymousUtils.html

I'm using the isLLinked method to figure out the loged in state of the user.

Comment: No. In my example, we've already established that user is a `currentUser` (anonymous or otherwise) cached one disk, so there is no reason to worry about ParseAnonymous users. And it's not android specific. the question is more so what's an example of a currentUser that isn't authenticated